# Lenovo Ideacentre Upgrade - Supported CPUs?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, compatibility, lenovo-desktop-computer, windows-11-upgrade

I'm attempting to upgrade a Lenovo Ideacentre 720-18asu to support Windows 11.  The motherboard has an AM4 socket, and previously had a Ryzen 7 1700 installed.  I purchased a Ryzen 7 5800x.

When I power on with the new CPU the PC does not boot - no beeps, no display, nothing.  I have checked for bent pins and power requirements (PSU is 400w).  Boots find if I swap back to the previous CPU. I've been able to find some basic specs for the motherboard, but nothing that indicates supported CPUs.

Did I get a defective CPU or is this one not compatible? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Additional Info:

- Updated to the latest BIOS provided by Lenovo - O38KT31A
- GPU is Radeon RX560
- The legend on the motherboard beside the socket is: "AM4MH"
- The FRU Label sticker on the motherboard says: "SPP0G98417 00xK239 for MB FRU WIN DPK"
- I've found a few links for refurbished replacements, but none with in-depth specs: https://pcpartsoutletstore.com/motherboards/lenovo-ideacentre-720-18asu-720-series-for-amd-cpu-desktop-motherboard-00xk239.html
- The closest I've come to actual specs is this document showing OEM configuration options: https://www.goodmoneysense.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/lenovo-ideacentre-720-specifications.pdf

Pics:
[Pic of Motherboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiUGb.jpg)
[Barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDU9f.jpg)
[FRU Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv1ku.jpg)

Comment: How did you determine that the CPU you purchased was compatible with your motherboard?  It doesn't sound like it is, your motherboard not turning on, the behavior you describe is a signed it's not compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Boots fine if I swap back to the previous CPU. ....   Did I get a
> defective CPU or is this one not compatible?

Unlikely the CPU is defective, but it is not on the Lenovo list for that Ideacenter.

I looked up the Lenovo PS REF for your machine and the CPU you show in your question is not on the PS REF.

[Lenovo PS Ref for Idea Center](https://psref.lenovo.com/Product/ideacentre_72018ASU?tab=spec)

You updated the BIOS (which is the only available suggestion).

So the upgrade does not work and there is not much at this point that you can do.

Return to the first CPU so that the machine runs.

Then consider a newer machine at a later time.